# ASP.NET Page Markup with Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question regarding the page markup of a hyperlink. I have a form view on an aspx page which has a datatable bound to it in the code behind. I have some controls on the aspx page that get data bound to them in the markup. I have a hyperlink control that needs one field bound to it in the text property (which I figured out) and one field bound to it in the hyperlink propoerty (which I need help with). I got the page to somewhat accept the markup, but when the link it clicked the link is somehow broken.

Also, can I not use the navigate URL property to navigate to an outside URL? Say, WWW.ESPN.COM? I think that is the problem...

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkCustom" NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebCustomHyper")%>' Target="_blank" CssClass="weblinks">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebCustomHyperDesc")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Also, can I not use the navigate URL property to navigate to an outside URL? Say, WWW.ESPN.COM? I think that is the problem...

Comment: What is the rendered link in the HTML on the client-side?  If the URL is `"www.espn.com"` then it's going to look for a resource called `"www.espn.com"` on the current website, because there's no indicator that it's a new URL.  You'd need it to be something like `"http://www.espn.com"` instead.

Comment: Glad it worked :)  I'll go ahead and make it into an answer to possibly help future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, can I not use the navigate URL property to navigate to an outside URL? Say, WWW.ESPN.COM? I think that is the problem...

Indeed that may very well be the problem.  It depends on what the rendered client-side markup looks like.  Let's say, for the sake of argument, that the page is at `http://www.example.com/page.aspx`.  Then if the link looks like this:

```
<a href="www.espn.com">click here</a>
```

Clicking it will try to take the user to:

```
http://www.example.com/www.espn.com
```

Which, of course, won't work.  This is because the value `www.espn.com` alone doesn't tell the browser that it should be going to a different location.  It's entirely possible that you have a file on the server called `www.espn.com` as far as the browser is concerned.

In order to direct it properly, you need to fully-qualify the URL.  Which basically means you need to prepend the protocol prefix.  Something more like this:

```
<a href="http://www.espn.com">click here</a>
```

This would fix the link and direct the user to the correct destination.